# Retrofit response array or object

Tags: java, android

Im have two difference response from api. Then I judge the object, but how do I return the contents of message to a string? The following example returns exception:

```
Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast
```

Json response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "message": "User created",
    }
}
```

Json response:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "data": [
        {
            "code": "existing_user_login",
            "message": "User Exist !"
        }
    ]
}
```

Model:

```
public class Response {
    public Boolean success;
    public Object data;

    public Boolean isSuccess() { return success; }

    public String getMessage() {
        if (data instanceof Data) {
            return ((Data) data).getMessage();
        } else if (data instanceof List) {
            try {
                return ((List<Data>) data).get(0).getMessage();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }

        } else return null;
    }


    public class Data {
        public String code;
        public String message;
        public String getMessage() { return message; }
        public String getCode() { return code; }
    }
}
```

Comment: apply the condition in a status variable like if the status is true then retrieve data{} object otherwise retrieve data array[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get message like this:

```
public String getMessage() {
    if (data instanceof Data) {
        return ((Data) data).getMessage();
    } else if (data instanceof List) {
        try {
             return (String) ((LinkedTreeMap) ((List) data).get(0)).get("message");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }

    } else return null;
}
```

Comment: Ok edited code, but: Response.getMessage() im given null.

Comment: Im given exception: Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast